# How to change Apk signed key from SHA-1 to SHA256

Tags: android, apk, signed, android-keystore, android-signing

I want to change the signed key of my Android application from SHA-1 to SHA-256.

I also want to know that does this change will affect my app which is already on the Google Play. I have added some new features to the app and now want to change the signed key to sha256 and upload it to the play-store to update the existing app no as a new app.
Can any one tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new key will prevent users with the old version from being able to update seamlessly. That's just the cold hard truth about changing signing keys for apps published in Google Play.

The suggested method for migrating is to update the existing app with a [Dialog](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) that provides an opportunity for the user to continue running the existing version or go to Play Store to install the new one (which will necessarily appear as a separate app in Play). The new app should check for the existence of the old one and remind the user to uninstall it.

You can keep the old app in the store so you don't lose your ratings and comments, just be sure to add a notice and link to the description pointing new users to the latest version.

[This article](https://guardianproject.info/2015/12/29/how-to-migrate-your-android-apps-signing-key/) was helpful to me when I was trying to understand.

Comment: The linked article was actually very helpful. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: There is way google is providing to update your sign in key, without loosing your app rating.